# Docker for Windows: error pulling image configuration: i/o timeout

Tags: docker

I have installed the latest version of Docker for Windows (1.12.1-stable, build 7135) on my Windows 10 Pro-64 bit. I was able to successfully execute `docker run hello-world`. However, when I do `docker run busybox`, an error is thrown as below.

```
C:\Users\testuser>docker run -it busybox
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox

8ddc19f16526: Pulling fs layer
docker: error pulling image configuration: Get https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/2b/2b8fd9751c4c0f5dd266fcae00707e67a2545ef34f9a29354585f93dac906749/data?Expires=1474617209&Signature=HRDYuDqnI3ERPonW9vj0HtP3hzIQoB1j7d-kWzR0iDXozoDknq0n4wIfkw2H73K5xaBBmVNy2ZoOqOQTm9LFP44MGfgS1pNthOLuEMSKrVUJmuaQNvckxuznuqffhkMCmTmQ7-~WMBjyLh7Si9sLdYR8oLVwN6sDRn5wKRa7f4I_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: dial tcp: i/o timeout.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The same error occurs for several other images. I do not have a proxy and have a stable internet connection. I have tried this with windows firewall enabled and disabled. I have also restarted the docker service.

Let me know if I am missing something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22567) with the networking stack in the current version of Docker for Windows.

The workaround is detailed in [remove stale network adapters](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#4-remove-stale-network-adapters): open the Network settings in Docker for Windows, and select the 'Fixed' DNS setting, using Google's DNS server `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: This needs more upvotes.  I was dealing with this for a day and a half before finally finding this simple solution.

Comment: I have faced the same issue for linux (Lubuntu). The answer you mention also works for me.

Comment: Same issue for debian 10, solution was helpful also.

Comment: same issue in debian 9. also helpful solution

Comment: Don't forget to restart the docker service!

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the similar issue while running Docker on Windows 10.

The issue got resolved by changing the DNS settings.
(Settings -> Network -> DNS Server -> 8.8.8.8 ( Automatic)

I observed that when the DNS server option was set to manual, the timeout issue still remains.

After making these changes, Docker service was restarted and I was able to pull the Docker image successfully.

regards,
dattatray.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting the DNS to fixed (and setting the target to 8.8.8.8) fixed it for me (after Docker restarted).